# warning: format '%s' expects argument of type 'char *', but argument 2 has type 'int'

Tags: array, c

Tengo este programa que pretende convertir un número decimal en hexadecimal. El tema es que el programa tira la advertencia de más arriba y no se como corregirlo. Se supone que la devolución (identificador de variable) debería ser un %s porque lo que se quiere mostrar es una cadena.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    char * hex = '\0';
    const char * DIG_HEX = "0123456789ABCDEF";
    printf ("Ingrese un entero positivo: ");
    scanf ("%d",&n);
    do{
        hex = DIG_HEX [n % 16] + hex;
        n = (int) n/16;
    }while ( n != 0 );
    printf ("\nHexadecimal= %s", hex);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: No hace falta que hagas tu la conversion, [`printf` tiene entre sus especificadores de formato uno que imprime un numero como hexadecimal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fprintf#Parameters).

Comment: Pasando de eso, `hex` no es una cadena, es un carácter nada mas. Y `hex = DIG_HEX [n % 16] + hex` no es la forma correcta de adjuntar caracteres a una cadena. Te recomendaria que regresaras a tu material de clase para repasar como se trabajan con cadenas.